# Can't connect to a PHP API

Tags: objective-c, web-services, cocoa, asihttprequest

I'm using the ASIHTTPRequest class for make some web services with my iPhone app. Here are some sample code I use for that

```
-(void)startRequest {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.myURL/iOS/objc.php"];
    //NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8888/API/objc.php"];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setPostValue:@"1" forKey:@"getWines"];
    [request startAsynchronous];
}
```

and obviously I catch the result in this function :

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {  
    NSString *result = request.responseString;
}
```

When I launch the simulator with the localhost URL

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8888/API/objc.php"];
```

My app works good. But when I

- Launch with my device
- Launch with the simulator to the server location

Nothing happens! I mean, the requestFinished is never called!

If I try with Google Chrome I got some answer, but with both of condition above nothing.

Comment: Well it isn't going to work on the device with the `localhost` url for obvious reasons.  Does it work _anywhere_ with the production url?

Comment: What do you mean with "Does it work anywhere with the production url?"?, Like if i run my apps on the simulator with the production url? In this case yes it works good.

Comment: Use CharlesProxy to see what is going on. Also try adding a handler for ASIHTTPRequest's requestFailed delegate method, as the request is almost certainly failing for some reason.

Comment: Will see and give you some feedback later, thank you

Comment: I get the message "Incorrect NSStringEncoding value 0x0000 detected. Assuming NSASCIIStringEncoding. Will stop this campability mapping behavior in the near futur". Does it mean that my server's response is wrong?

Comment: @Edelweiss: It means you specified a bogus encoding value (namely, zero) when creating a string from some data. You should look at whether you did this or ASIHTTPRequest did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what was wrong with, this is because I wrote

"www.myURL/iOS/objc.php"

Instead of

"http://www.myURL/iOS/objc.php",

change everythings !